# Why half-wave dipole is the most efficient one in comparison to other electrical lengths?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength, dipole, antennas

I have a problem on the understanding of a half-wavelength antenna. Namely, why is the half-wave antenna has a highest power emission. Considering Far Field factor F($\theta$), which is known from the following formula:

\begin{equation}
|F(\theta)|^2= \frac{ (\cos{( \frac{kl} {2} \cos{\theta})} - \cos{ \frac{kl} {2} })^2 } {\sin^2{\theta}},
\end{equation}
where $k$ is wavenumber, $2*l$ is a total dipole length, $\theta$ is a an angle from the antenna axis.

That factor corresponds to the wave power. It seems like , that  the highest Far field is for kl/2 = Pi. One can check that considering $\theta = 0$, and demanding the highest $|F(\theta)|^2$. By the way, the plot corresponding to different electrical length is shown on the following figure. One can see the highest $|F(\theta)|^2$ for $kl = 2\pi$.

[image: Dipole antenna Far field factor]

So could I ask you where is the problem in the latter? Should one condisder reflections of feed signal from the antenna or other things?

Comment: What do you mean by "highest power emission"? To what are comparing it?

Comment: Are you asking about field strength, or about efficiency, i.e. radiated power vs. driving power?

Comment: Comparing power between different electric length. I am interested in radiated power vs driving power. And the antenna gain. There might be simply something that i do not understand. I wonder why the half wave antenna is used.

Comment: Petr, i recommend you post this question on the amateur radio stack exchange, lots of friendly antenna experts over there.

Comment: Ok, Niels, I will do that